# How to i get the searchbar in android to retain the search text in the search results view?

Tags: java, android

Like in google play, i want the search text to appear in the search bar in action bar in search activity. Currently it just disappears. How do i retain the search-bar and search text while displaying results in another view

In main activity i have

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

In search activity i have

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.booklisting);
        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string

        handleIntent(getIntent());
         //Intent intent = getIntent();
        //String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
         //execute_search(message);




    }

    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Handling intent data
     */
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            execute_search(query);

        }

    }
```